# Get a Signed Request from Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, encryption, sdk

I'm trying to get a signed request from Facebook's Android SDK in order to securely pass it to the server side, but so far I could not find a way to do that.

I've found a similar question for iOS ([Facebook iOS SDK to return a signed request object upon login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874091/facebook-ios-sdk-to-return-a-signed-request-object-upon-login)) but with no (useful) answer there.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be achieved (without storing the secret in the Android app and encrypting the access token there)?

Cheers.

Comment: It is explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#architecture

Comment: Thanks @WizKid, but I couldn't find any mention of "signed request" on that link.

Comment: What do you need a signed request for?

Comment: To pass it over to a server (the server has the secret for the app ID and everything).

Comment: You pass the access token to the server. That what I is explained on the page I liked to

Comment: Ahh, right. But that's the thing, I would rather pass the 'signed request', which is encrypted and only the server can decrypt, rather than the plain access token that anyone who has it could use it.

Comment: @daniel.comsa did you solve the problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately. I gave up on that idea.