# Facebook SDK IOS returns signed request object

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

- Is it possible to get signed request object from `Facebook IOS SDK`?
- Whether `Facebook IOS SDK` returns signed request object?
- If not, How can i get the signed request object upon login using `Facebook IOS SDK`?

Comment: Take a look at this stack url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874091/facebook-ios-sdk-to-return-a-signed-request-object-upon-login

Comment: @crisu Thanks for your quick response. I think proper answer is not given in the link you posted.